# Как сделать правильное преобразование базового класса в производный?

Tags: c#

Решил расширить возможности `ObservableCollection` и сделал подобное:

```
public class HandledObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
...
}
```

Однако, когда мне нужно получить из базового класса `ObservableCollection` мой производный `HandledObservableCollection`, то по логикe я должен написать просто что-то на подобии `HandledObservableCollection<MyType> MyHandledCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();`. Однако компилятор в таком случае не допускает, что это возможно и говорит, что нельзя преобразовать `ObservableCollection<T>` в `HandledObservableCollection<T>`.

Re# подсказывает, что нужно написать вот так - `HandledObservableCollection<MyType> MyHandledCollection = (HandledObservableCollection<MyType>) new ObservableCollection<MyType>();`.

Однако в данном случае мы получаем следующую ошибку:

[image]

Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Если вы хотите расширить возможности типа - вам нужно создать свой тип и использовать паттерн декоратор для вызова унаследованной логики. Однако из базового класса достать производный вы не сможете - везде где вам нужно использовать расширенные возможности по сравнению с базовым классом вам нужно использовать не базовый класс, который это не умеет, а свой расширенный.

Comment: *то по логикe я должен написать просто что-то на подобии* — странная логика. А вообще вопрос про понятен, опишите подробнее что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Это наследника можно привести к базовому типу, потому что в нем есть все методы базового типа. Экземпляр родителя нельзя привести к производному типу, потому что в производном есть функции, которые базовый класс не поддерживает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите расширить возможности типа, то вызывать на базовом типе расширенные возможности у вас не получится - он о них просто не знает. ) Поэтому если у вас есть базовые возможности в каком-то типе MyTypeA - то чтобы их использовать вам нужно создавать объект этого типа, а когда нужны расширенные возможности класса MyTypeB то вам нужно создавать объект расширенного типа и пользоваться его возможностями.

```
public class MyTypeA
{
    public void Execute(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyTypeA: {data}");
    }
}


public class MyTypeB
{
    public MyTypeB()
    {
        this.MyTypeA = new MyTypeA();
    }

    public MyTypeA MyTypeA { get; private set; }

    public void Execute(string data)
    {
        // proxy method to decorated obj
        this.MyTypeA.Execute(data);
    }

    public void Extended(string data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"MyTypeB Extended: {data}");
    }
}
```

Правильное использование:

```
var a = new MyTypeA();
a.Execute("wow");

var b = new MyTypeB();
b.Execute("wow");
b.Extended("wow");
```

Неправильное использование (аналогичное тому, как вы пытаетесь сделать):

```
var a = (MyTypeB) new MyTypeA();
```

Мало того, что вы не сделаете подобное приведение - так даже приведя тип вы не сможете вызвать расширенную логику, её там просто нет:

```
a.Extended("wow");
```

Можно в какой-то мере замаскировать использование расширенного класса, используя методы расширения (extenstion) когда какбы на классе типа А вызываются методы типа Б, однако по факту это лишь синтаксический сахар для вызова метода расширения с параметром класса А.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял вас. Тогда вопрос - есть реализация, как в этом ответе - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299957/8361539 (да, знаю - `ObservableCollection` предоставляет события изменения коллекции, но мне нужно раздельно добавление и убирание), у меня на входе есть `ObservableCollection`, как из нее сделать мой класс `HandledObservableCollection`, если не делать так, как вы предложили?

Comment: @SKProCH Никак.

Comment: Расширение базовых возможностей класса возможно через а) наследование либо б) композицию (декорирование). Наследование здесь менее уместно: при композиции вы сможете запретить вызывать update, при наследовании - нет.